# How to deploy GAS web app with limited access

Tags: android-studio, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace

I have a app builded in android studio which is a simple searchable database. I use a function doGet(in the apps script) to fetch data from a gsheet. Everything works well, but the real gsheet I need is in the local domain of my company(stored in a Shared Drive) so when I try to deploy the apps script as a web app I can't set permission to anyone(limited only to user of company). The response of the url is so a blank page.
Is there a method to get around this trouble?

Update: I also tried to add a Google sign in page when opening the app but still doesn't work

Comment: Have you discussed the matter with your admin?

Comment: Please be more specific about "I can't set permission to anyone". Are you the spreadsheet owner or it's owned by an individual or the company (stored in a Shared Drive rather the "My Drive" of a user account)? The doGet function is part your Android Studio app or is part of a Google Apps Script project?